# DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-302, DRIVER=3.65.97

Tags: db2

When I have searched for "DB2 SQL

> Error: SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, SQLERRMC=null"

I got to know that we get this error due to 
*"THE VALUE OF INPUT VARIABLE OR PARAMETER NUMBER position-number IS INVALID OR TOO LARGE FOR THE TARGET COLUMN OR THE TARGET VALUE, position"* and number should give you the number of the column that is causing your troubles.

In that case Is it the "driver" column causing trouble for error message

> "com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-302,
>   SQLSTATE=22001, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.65.97"

for this case Do I have to add driver or do I have to change any driver? If I have to change driver which driver do I have to change??

Comment: Check this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21585238

Comment: Thanks for the link Rahul.. we are using db2 sql.. Can you suggest where can I find logging.property file